# Problems importing scipy.integrate module

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a reoccurring issue with importing the integrate module of scipy.

Periodically, I get the Error message "ImportError: cannot import name integrate".
Usually, I use the statement `import scipy.integrate` to import the module.

Only using `import scipy` successfully imports scipy but without the integrate module.

The funny thing is that this behavior can change each time I start Python. So sometimes it works fine even when the same script is run.

Anybody has any suggestions?

Comment: how did you install it? what does `from scipy import test; test()` show?

Comment: Hello Zhenya, thanks for your answer. The command produces the following output. 

`Running unit tests for scipy`
`NumPy version 1.8.0`
`NumPy is installed in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy`
`SciPy version 0.13.1`
`SciPy is installed in scipy`
`Python version 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`
`nose version 1.3.0`
After this statement I get the following error message:
`WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'scipy/*.*'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My issue was that python-2.7 would not let me import scipy.integrate, but python-3.x would allow the import.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a professional, but I had the issue with importing of **scipy.integrate** package even after successful installing of scipy package via '`pip install scipy`'.
The Error was '

> No module named 'scipy.special

'.
I randomly solved the issue, maybe my solution will be applicable in your case.

Briefly:
I use Python3 and for installing packages it is better to use '`pip3`' command, not '`pip`'.

More details:
So initially, I had used '`pip install scipy`' and this didn't work.
When I tried to use '`pip3 install scipy`', there was a message saying that all the requirement are satisfied, but **scipy.integrate** still was unavailable with the same Error.
When I tried to uninstall scipy via '`pip uninstall scipy`' there was a message that scipy is not installed (but actually, it still was installed).
So I went to '`C:\Users\{username.username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages`' and deleted the folder named '`scipy`'.
Thereafter, I reran the command '`pip3 install scipy`' and everything was installed successfully and the following commands worked well in my Jupyter Notebook:
'

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special
```

'

The following functions became available: `quad, dblquad, tplquad, odeint, ode` via the:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad, tplquad
```

and

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint, ode
```